# Create file path based on XML file name

Tags: xslt, gruntjs, xslt-1.0

Is there a way to create the grunt build that file path is coming from file name?

I have:

```
xsltproc: {
      options: {
        stylesheet: 'templates/xmlCompiler.xsl'
      },
      compile: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'resources/dist/xml',
          src: '*.xml',
          dest: 'build',
          ext: '.html'
        }]
      }
    },
```

Which basically will create .html file based on .xml file. Now, I have a task to create every HTML file to have structure of:

build/xmlfilename/index.html

eg: 
xml file: xml/**aa.xml**, xml/**bb.xml**, xml/**cc.xml**.
After the build it becomes: build/**aa**/index.html, build/**bb**/index.html, build/**cc**/index.html.

It tried to look on the documentations but I couldn't find any. Do you guys have any idea or link to direct me?

Comment: Welcome at SO! You could highlight/structure/format your example a bit and work on the first sentence, which I find confusing to read. Have fun!

Comment: I just re-wording my question. Thanks Felix for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I have a task to create every HTML file to have structure of:
>   build/xmlfilename/index.html

An HTML file does not have a file structure, it is basically just a text file. I assume you mean that you want to process multiple XML files and you want to store them in different directories?

Assuming you use XSLT 2.0 (otherwise it wouldn't be possible to create multiple result document anyway), you can do the following:

```
<xsl:template name="main">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('xml/*.xml')" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="replace(base-uri(), '.xml', '/')" />
    <xsl:result-document href="{$path}index.html">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

This code assumes that your processor will automatically create the directory if it does not exist. If it doesn't do that, you should resort to extension functions (or write a `UriResolver`, which most processors support in some way). But since you did not give any information about what processor you use, I cannot advice much further.

Comment: Thanks Abel. I didn't know XSLT can be a possible solution. I'm looking into it now, but I got grunt build failed on <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('../resources/dist/xml/*.xml')"/>. "../resources/dist/xml" is the structure of the XML. For tthe processor that you're talking about, you mean by xsltproc in grunt (grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-xsltproc');)?

Comment: @hmuljono, I am not familiar with Grunt, but when I check [xsltproc for GruntJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-xsltproc) I see that it is a plugin to a commandline. However, the bundled processor is xsltproc, which is XSLT 1.0 (1999). Your task is **far from trivial in XSLT 1.0** (without ext. functions). Perhaps you can choose a different processor? There are roughly four or five XSLT 2.0 (since 2007) processors on the market: [Saxon](http://saxonica.com), [Exselt](http://exselt.net) (my own), [XmlPrime](http://xmlprime.com), [Altova Raptor](http://www.altova.com/raptorxml.html).